# Words for smug, evil look?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for words to describe that classic smug and evil facial expression. Something similar to this emoji - . I was thinking *mischievous* but that word doesn't adequately connote the evil nature of the look I'm thinking of. Maybe a *conniving* look? That doesn't sound right to me either.

Sample sentences could be... "

> The killer had a look of ______ when the woman walked into a pitch-black alley.

or

> The thief's face made a _____ expression which betrayed his intention to commit larceny".

I also considered *lascivious* but I don't want a sexual connotation. It has to be a pure, murderous evil mixed in with delight.

Ideally I'm looking for a single word adjective/noun but I'd love to hear interesting similes and idiomatic expressions as well.

Comment: What's wrong with "evil look"?

Comment: _Malicious_? (NB You want a noun in your first sample sentence, an adjective in your second.)

Comment: The [emoji](https://www.dictionary.com/e/emoji/smiling-face-with-horns-emoji/) is commonly described as "smiling face with horns". (Which isn't much help in finding a shorter name.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could think of only one word.

[Sadistic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sadistic#English) (Wiktionary):Delighting in or feeling pleasure from the pain or humiliation of others.
Of behaviour which gives pleasure in the pain or humiliation of others.
(colloquial) Causing a high degree of pain or humiliation.

> The killer had a look of **sadistic pleasure (or "a sadist")** when
> the woman walked into a pitch-black alley.
>
> The thief's face made a **sadistic** expression which betrayed his
> intention to commit larceny".

Comment: You also see phrases like "sadistic grin" a lot (examples: [Adobe](https://stock.adobe.com/uk/images/facial-expression-funny-sadistic-grin/2098990), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/hveehq/look_at_this_sadistic_grin/), [American Journal of Medicine](https://www.amjmed.com/article/S0002-9343(18)30868-4/pdf), etc.)

Comment: Yep, that's the word right there. Fits perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

*Evil look* would be fine in my opinion, but there is also ***vicious***:

> ***Vicious*** people or actions *show an intention or wish to hurt someone or something very badly*:
>
> - The police said that this was one of the most ***vicious attacks*** they'd ever seen.
> - He gave her ***a vicious look***. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vicious))

Some synonyms of *evil-looking* might help:

> ***[ominous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ominous), [eerie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eerie), [malignant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malignant)*** etc. ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/evil-looking.html))

So I would write your first sentence as:

> The killer had ***a vicious look*** when the woman walked into a pitch-black alley.

The second sentence might read better as

> The *vicious/ominous expression* of thief's face betrayed his intention to commit larceny.

Comment: Yeah these are all great words at describing evil but not smug and happy, that seems like the hard part.

Answer (score 0):

> The thief's face made a **truculent** expression which betrayed his intention to commit larceny.

**Truculent**, via the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/206875) (def 1a):

> Characterized by or exhibiting ferocity or cruelty; fierce, cruel, savage, barbarous.

Sometimes the manner is primarily ferocious, sometimes more cruel. Sometimes the word has a sense of fierce or cruel *glee*. One of the sample sentences from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truculent) captures that sense for me:

> … in the breast pocket of her police uniform she carried a small silver figurine of Durga, the Hindu goddess of shakti: power and strength. Defiant and **truculent**, she flashed a cheeky grin. (Mary Anne Weaver, Atlantic, November 1996)